# Save/Validate Entity

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm a novice with domain driven design and learning to apply it in my current project. I hope some of you guys have already walked the path and can help me out.

I have a question with regard to saving UI changes back to an Entity (Order).

The scenario:
a. An approver opens the Order (Aggregate root) pending approval on the Web. Makes some changes and clicks the button "Approve".
b. The UI translates the Order changes to a DTO and posts it across to a Web service for processing.
c. The service pulls the Order from OrderRepository via say call to orderRep.GetByID(ApplicationNumber)

Question
1. How do I post the UI changes available in the OrderDTO to Order?
2. What are the different things I need to take care while hydrating the Order?
   (If we have to ensure that the domain object (Order) doesn't land up in 
    invalid state due to changes)

Answer (score 0):

Each user operation should correspond to a different command method in the application service layer.  Much of the time it will correspond to exactly one call on a domain object.

You probably don't have fine-grained enough methods on your Order domain object.

`Approve()` should probably only be a method, not a public setter.  Throw an exception within `Approve()` if it would place the `Order` object in an invalid state.